# How can capture args with xargs across multiple pipe in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, xargs

I have this command

```
kubectl get ns -l app=sample-api | awk '/fast/{print $1}' |
xargs -I {} helm list --short -n {} | xargs -I {} helm delete -n ?? {}
```

Suppose that argument from first xargs is $1 and it gets subsituted in like `helm list --short -n {$1}`

and $2 is the argument of second Xargs and its gets substituted like

```
helm delete -n ?? {$2}
```

but i also want $1 to use like this in last comand

```
helm delete -n {$1} {$2}
```

is this possible ?

output of first xargs

```
name1
name2
name3
```

second xargs

```
chart1
chart2
chart3
```

Comment: What is the output of the first `xargs`? Just a single label?

Comment: @tripleee added info in question

Comment: And you want to `helm delete -n name1 chart1`, then `helm delete -n name2 chart2`? Or should it remove all charts for each name?

Comment: @tripleee yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply break it up into a separate loop.

```
kubectl get ns -l app=sample-api |
awk '/fast/{print $1}' |
while read -r name; do
    target=$(helm list --short -n "$name")
    helm delete -n "$name" "$target"
done
```

As discussed in comments, if you need this in a Makefile, you'll need to indent every line with a tab, double all the dollar signs, add semicolons between statements, and backslash-escape the internal newlines:

```
.PHONY: kill_em_all
kill_em_all:
    kubectl get ns -l app=sample-api |\
    awk '/fast/{print $$1}' |\
    while read -r name; do\
        target=$$(helm list --short -n "$$name");\
        helm delete -n "$$name" "$$target";\
    done
```

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow still renders tabs as spaces, so you will not be able to copy/paste this into a `Makefile` directly.

Comment: is it possible to do i xargs only ? or single line ?

Comment: Every newline can be replaced with a semicolon, except after `do`. I don't see a sane way to do this with `xargs`.

Comment: Can i put this whole block inside Make file? like make delete.charts , by replacing $ with $$ ?

Comment: Yes, every piece of shell script will work in `make` too, but you have to double the dollar signs, and baokslash-escape any internal newlines.

Comment: Make is complaining about end of file , do i have to use \ at the end

Comment: Updated the answer with an example.